# setOrientationHint() does nothing on Gingerbread, but works on later versions

Tags: android

I am trying to record a video in `portrait orientation`.

Setting the Camera `DisplayOrientation` to 90 degrees makes the preview to video be displayed in `portrait`.

But When calling `setOrientationHint()` with any given number(0,90,180,270) the video that was created is created always in portrait orientation.

When I have tested it on Jellybean and on ICS, the video orientation was the one I set with the `setOrientationHint()` method.

Here is the `MediaRecorder` initialization code:

```
private void initRecorder() {
    Camera camera = Camera.open();
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    camera.unlock();
    recorder.reset();
    recorder.setCamera(camera);
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
    file = new File("/sdcard/test.mp4");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    recorder.setOrientationHint(90);//doesn't seem to work on 2.3

    recorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
    recorder.setMaxDuration(30000);
    recorder.setMaxFileSize(1000000);
}
```

And this is where I prepare the `MediaRecorder`:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    this.holder = holder;
        recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

**Tested on:**

1. Samsung Galaxy S running android 2.2.
2. Samsung Galaxy W running android 2.3.
3. Samsung galaxy S2 running ICS - **worked**.
4. Samsung galaxy s3 running Jelly Bean - **worked**.

Comment: Are you testing on physical devices or emulator?
What are you devices?

Comment: @Hartok I have edited my answer with the devices, and I couldn't test it on an amulator, atleast not capture a video.

I have played the video on my computer to check the orientation.

Comment: have you checked the metadata of the videos? What could be happening: 2.3 only writes the angle into the metadata, but is ignored on playback- but 4.0 ++ will actually rotate the video after recording

Answer (score 2):

`setOrientationHint()` needs to be called before `prepare()`. Check if this is happening.

Also note that this method only works for `3gpp` and `mpeg4` formats and some video players choose to ignore this property completely. The video players you are using might be ignoring it.

Comment: It throws an exception otherwise, I am already calling it before the 'prepare' and the format is mp4.

And the video player I am using is not ignoring is since it has shown the right orientation when I recorded with a devices running ICS&Jelly Bean.

Comment: which video player are you testing it on? Is it the stock player that comes with the device or a third party player like vlc?

Comment: both on vlc, and I am testing it in a simple activity with a videoview in portrait mode.